# how to ask if any date format fit to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to ask in C# Winform if this format: `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy` == true

then convert to `dd/MM/yyyy` format

thank's in advance

Comment: If what, a string? Date? A control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TryParseExact().  Followed by DateTime.ToString() to convert.  For example:

```
    public static string ConvertDate(string arg) {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(arg, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", null, 
              System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt)) {
            return dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        // Consider what to return on failure...
        return null;
    }
```

Test case:

```
    string s = ConvertDate("Fri Jul 23 10:21:00 2010");
```